# Xamarin.iOS google mobile ad banner not appearing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I grabbed the nuget package Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds, currently on 7.27.0 and have it installed in my iOS project

Inside the .xib I'm trying to add the banner to, I created a blank view at the bottom that is meant to act as the banner holder.

[image]

My Code looks like this

```
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        SetupMenuViews();
        SetupBannerView();

    }

        private void SetupBannerView()
    {



        var banner = new BannerView(bannerView.Frame)
        {
            AdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716",
            RootViewController = this,
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All,   
        };

        //View.AddSubview(banner);

        bannerView.AddSubview(banner);
        bannerView.BringSubviewToFront(banner);

        banner.LoadRequest(Google.MobileAds.Request.GetDefaultRequest());


    }
```

Problem is..nothing is appearing, has anyone had any luck using AdMob with Xamarin.iOS or can spot anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you mixing `UIViewAutoresizingMask` and constraints? You are going to have a bad time because of this.

Comment: Was just something I was trying, too see if it would have any effect.  Even removed it does not appear

Comment: What are your constraints on the view?

Comment: Trailing Space: Superview, Leading Space: Superview, Bottom Space, Superview, height = 50.  The view appears fine If I change the background color...but it just never populates an ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who happens to run into this problem.  No matter what the docs say, I couldn't get a banner working by having a pre-set size.  The fix is to have the size set to that of a smart banner

```
        private void SetupBannerView()
    {



        BannerView bannerAdd = new BannerView(AdSizeCons.SmartBannerPortrait);
        bannerAdd.AdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
        bannerAdd.RootViewController = this;

        bannerView.AddSubview(bannerAdd);
        bannerView.BringSubviewToFront(bannerAdd);

        bannerAdd.LoadRequest(Google.MobileAds.Request.GetDefaultRequest());

    }
```